# Implementing movement of tree leaves with wind in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am trying to implement an OpenGL program which will show the movement of leaves of a tree with the wind.As a starting point I have written the following idle() function

```
zh=0;

void idle()
 {
  double t=glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)/1000.0;
  zh=sin(t);
  glutPostRedisplay();
 }
```

for the vertices used to form the leaves I tried using

```
glVertex3f(x,y,z+zh);
```

using `zh=sint(t)` does not provide the desired movement of leaves with wind.Could anyone suggest any other equation that might work well?

Answer (score 1):

*Insert standard remark that fixed function pipeline is deprecated*

I suggest using shaders for this, the time parameter can then be passed in a uniform and the position adjusted (and normal recalculated) accordingly. That way you can also offset the animation differently for each leaf.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can not answer your question. To simulate realistically I believe you would need advanced methods.

For cheap experimentation I would suggest trying to alter your `x` or `y` coordinate instead of `z` coordinate and see how it looks like.

Another thing, it seems that you alter each leaf with the same transformation. Randomize them a bit.